# Apache poi getColumn width is bringing the instance down

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, apache-poi, heap-dump

My instances go down because of heap space issue frequently and when I take the thread dump it is always failing at

```
Current CompileTask:
**C2:8428**  ! //The number will vary  org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet;IZ)D (799 bytes)
  JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12321
```

This is a compiler thread and it is requesting for nearly 18gb of memory when it fails.

We are using apache po version 3.8-beta4.

I am not using getColumnWidth function anywhere but look like the autoSize method is calling this function.

Any idea why this should request for 18gb of mem and why it is a compiler thread?

The application server is Jboss 5

Comment: Please show the relevant code that calls `autoSize`, plus any other relevant details, such as any stack trace and the size of the data in the sheet/workbook.

Comment: I have had issue with autoSize() performance in large spreadsheets.  In my experience it's better to calculate and set the size yourself.

Comment: I am  not sure which autoSize code is brining it down it is just a compiler thread and i am not able to identify which thread is getting invoked.

Comment: Why are you using a very old Beta version of Apache POI? Does the problem go away with the latest stable version? And have you made sure you're using the latest JVM update (and not an old an possibly buggy one)?